# Which of AppFramework equivalent jQM

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

I need advice on, which of Intel AppFramework Page Event equivalent to jQM following Page Event?

- pagebeforecreate
- pagecreate
- pageinit
- pagebeforehide
- pagehide
- pagebeforeshow
- pageshow
- pageremove
- pagebeforeload
- pageload
- pagebeforechange
- pagechange

Please advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ian answered your question on the XDK forum (https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=6298). He indicated he will try to implement those events in App Framework.

You might also be interested in the pointer to the documentation for the events available in App Framework, which are here: http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui_events.

Comment: Thanks. I've just replied to him. Hope I can get some clearly idea on how to load content dynamically in AF Page everytime the page is accessed.